# clean the object when the values are duplicate in java

Tags: java, mysql, exception, duplicates

I'm adding data to my db, but I realized this; every time I tried to add a duplicate row I have this message from the console:

> e = >(com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '13-2-1' for key 'idx_post_user'

The thing is the object still has the values from the html form, so when I try to compare the object with a null to select which way I'm going to take (send to a or b screen), the object still has the parameters duplicated in memory.

My question is: How can I clean the object in my code after the exception to use an if condition?

```
public boolean addElement(Object objetoInsert) {
    ContactPost objContactPost = (ContactPost) objetoInsert;
    try {
        Connection con = Conexion.getConexion();
        String query = "insert into snp_contactpost values 
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setInt(1, ultimoID());
        ps.setInt(2, objContactPost.getPost_id());
        ps.setInt(3, objContactPost.getContactPost_isDone());
        ps.setString(4, objContactPost.getContactPost_token());
        ps.setInt(5, objContactPost.getUser_id_seller());
        ps.setInt(6, objContactPost.getUser_id_buyer());
        ps.setInt(7, objContactPost.getContactPost_isEmailSended());
        ps.setString(8, objContactPost.getContactPost_date());
        try {
            return ps.executeUpdate() == 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clean the object"?

Comment: i mean, the object can not be null, and after the message, most of the values are still in the object. so thats why in a certain way i need to clean or erase the object... or  make it null

Answer (score 0):

try closing your connection with `con.close();` before the nested try.

Comment: but still the object its full of data. and its causing me troubles when i evaluate in my servlet